How to use boost log in visual studio 2015 and build platform is v140
I have added all the dependencies but after adding it i am getting some linking error. I am using visual studio 2015 buildtool v140 , platform v8.1 and platform win32.
I have added the necessary dependencies.

boost.1.85.0'
boost_atomic-vc140.1.85.0
boost_chrono-vc140.1.85.0
boost_filesystem-vc140.1.85.0
boost_log-vc140.1.85.0
boost_log_setup-vc140.1.85.0
boost_thread-vc140.1.85.0

Linking errors:
Creating library ..\..\bin\lib\xLogger.lib and object ..\..\bin\lib\xLogger.exp
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::stream_provider<char>::release_compound(struct boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::stream_provider<char>::stream_compound *)" (?release_compound@?$stream_provider@D@aux@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@SAXPAUstream_compound@12345@@Z)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::stream_provider<char>::stream_compound * __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::stream_provider<char>::allocate_compound(class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::record &)" (?allocate_compound@?$stream_provider@D@aux@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@SAPAUstream_compound@12345@AAVrecord@345@@Z)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::attach_attribute_name_info(class boost::exception &,class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::attribute_name const &)" (?attach_attribute_name_info@aux@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@YAXAAVexception@4@ABVattribute_name@234@@Z)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::id<struct boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::process> __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::this_process::get_id(void)" (?get_id@this_process@aux@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@YA?AV?$id@Uprocess@aux@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@@2345@XZ)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::attribute_name __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::default_attribute_names::process_id(void)" (?process_id@default_attribute_names@aux@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@YA?AVattribute_name@345@XZ)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::attribute_name __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::default_attribute_names::message(void)" (?message@default_attribute_names@aux@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@YA?AVattribute_name@345@XZ)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::attribute_name __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::default_attribute_names::thread_id(void)" (?thread_id@default_attribute_names@aux@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@YA?AVattribute_name@345@XZ)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::attribute_name __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::default_attribute_names::timestamp(void)" (?timestamp@default_attribute_names@aux@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@YA?AVattribute_name@345@XZ)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::attribute_name __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::default_attribute_names::line_id(void)" (?line_id@default_attribute_names@aux@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@YA?AVattribute_name@345@XZ)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::code_convert_impl(wchar_t const *,unsigned int,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &,unsigned int,class std::locale const &)" (?code_convert_impl@aux@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@YA_NPB_WIAAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@IABVlocale@6@@Z)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::once_block_sentry::rollback(void)" (?rollback@once_block_sentry@aux@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@AAEXXZ)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: bool __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::once_block_sentry::enter_once_block(void)const " (?enter_once_block@once_block_sentry@aux@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@ABE_NXZ)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::once_block_sentry::commit(void)" (?commit@once_block_sentry@aux@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@QAEXXZ)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::id<struct boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::thread> const & __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::this_thread::get_id(void)" (?get_id@this_thread@aux@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@YAABV?$id@Uthread@aux@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@@2345@XZ)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::attribute_value_set::const_iterator __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::attribute_value_set::find(class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::attribute_name)const " (?find@attribute_value_set@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@QBE?AVconst_iterator@1234@Vattribute_name@234@@Z)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::attribute_value_set::const_iterator __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::attribute_value_set::end(void)const " (?end@attribute_value_set@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@QBE?AVconst_iterator@1234@XZ)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sources::severity_logger_mt<enum boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::trivial::severity_level> & __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::trivial::logger::get(void)" (?get@logger@trivial@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@SAAAV?$severity_logger_mt@W4severity_level@trivial@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@@sources@345@XZ)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point::operator()(void)const " (??Rrotation_at_time_point@file@sinks@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@QBE_NXZ)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point::rotation_at_time_point(unsigned char,unsigned char,unsigned char)" (??0rotation_at_time_point@file@sinks@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@QAE@EEE@Z)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sinks::text_file_backend::construct(class boost::filesystem::path const &,class boost::filesystem::path const &,int,unsigned __int64,class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::aux::light_function<bool __cdecl(void)> const &,enum boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sinks::auto_newline_mode,bool,bool)" (?construct@text_file_backend@sinks@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@AAEXABVpath@filesystem@5@0H_KABV?$light_function@$$A6A_NXZ@aux@345@W4auto_newline_mode@2345@_N4@Z)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sinks::text_file_backend::flush(void)" (?flush@text_file_backend@sinks@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@QAEXXZ)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sinks::text_file_backend::consume(class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::record_view const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?consume@text_file_backend@sinks@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@QAEXABVrecord_view@345@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: unsigned __int64 __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sinks::text_file_backend::scan_for_files(enum boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sinks::file::scan_method,bool)" (?scan_for_files@text_file_backend@sinks@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@QAE_KW4scan_method@file@2345@_N@Z)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sinks::text_file_backend::set_file_collector(class boost::shared_ptr<struct boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sinks::file::collector> const &)" (?set_file_collector@text_file_backend@sinks@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@QAEXABV?$shared_ptr@Ucollector@file@sinks@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@@5@@Z)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sinks::text_file_backend::~text_file_backend(void)" (??1text_file_backend@sinks@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@QAE@XZ)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "unsigned __int64 & __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sources::aux::get_severity_level(void)" (?get_severity_level@aux@sources@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@YAAA_KXZ)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static unsigned int __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::attribute_name::get_id_from_string(char const *)" (?get_id_from_string@attribute_name@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@CAIPBD@Z)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::record_view::public_data::destroy(struct boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::record_view::public_data const *)" (?destroy@public_data@record_view@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@SAXPBU12345@@Z)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::attribute::impl::operator delete(void *,unsigned int)" (??3impl@attribute@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@SAXPAXI@Z)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void * __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::attribute::impl::operator new(unsigned int)" (??2impl@attribute@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@SAPAXI@Z)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::core::push_record_move(class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::record &)" (?push_record_move@core@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@AAEXAAVrecord@234@@Z)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::record __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::core::open_record(class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::attribute_set const &)" (?open_record@core@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@QAE?AVrecord@234@ABVattribute_set@234@@Z)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: struct std::pair<class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::attribute_set::iter<0>,bool> __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::core::add_global_attribute(class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::attribute_name const &,class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::attribute const &)" (?add_global_attribute@core@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@QAE?AU?$pair@V?$iter@$0A@@attribute_set@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@_N@std@@ABVattribute_name@234@ABVattribute@234@@Z)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::core::add_sink(class boost::shared_ptr<class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::sinks::sink> const &)" (?add_sink@core@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@QAEXABV?$shared_ptr@Vsink@sinks@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@@4@@Z)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::core::set_filter(class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::filter const &)" (?set_filter@core@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@QAEXABVfilter@234@@Z)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::core::get_logging_enabled(void)const " (?get_logging_enabled@core@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@QBE_NXZ)
xLogger.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class boost::shared_ptr<class boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::core> __cdecl boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::core::get(void)" (?get@core@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@SA?AV?$shared_ptr@Vcore@v2s_mt_nt6@log@boost@@@4@XZ)

Please suggest, how I can solve this.

This section in the docs might help.

There is a generic topic for this kind of problems. If it doesn't help, you need to provide some https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , with info about your system setup, compiling commands, etc.
